# Who developed the vowels for the Hebrew language Ezra or the Masoretes?

Tags: history, vowels-nekudot

I've read that Ezra developed pointings to serve as vowels. 200 years later, when the Bible was translated from Hebrew to Greek, all Hebrew manuscripts had the new form of writing.
Who developed the system of notation for recording the vowels?
Ezra or the Masoretes?